# expo run:ios is not working due to AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x692883833b500> F8BC4C28-BNE8-15D6-9T31-85849315CD46

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I tried to run a react native expo project using these steps:

1. Pull the updated code
2. delete `node_module`
3. `npm install`
4. `cd /ios` and `pod install`

iOS - `expo run:ios`
Android - `expo run:android`

But for `expo run:ios` I got below error

```
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x692883833b500> F8BC4C28-BNE8-15D6-9T31-858449315CD46
```

How can I resolve this error and run the app on device.

Note: App is running when I start using `yarn start` or `npm run`. I need above method because this is the easiest way to use a native module in our application without ejecting the expo app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following steps to fix this:

1. In Xcode, go to `File->Project/Workspace settings`.
2. Change the build system to `Legacy Build system`.

It will resolve the build issue with the new Xcode.